# Initialize Service in Blazor Webassembly

Tags: asynchronous, .net-core, blazor, asp.net-core-webapi, webassembly

I've got a service A that is shared among various components. That service needs to be initialized at startup with values from a WebApi.

How can I accomplish that? I tried two things.

_1.

In program.cs/main method I do

```
builder.Services.AddScoped
```

with A and other services B and C.

Then I call a method

```
async LoadSetupData(wasmBuilder)
```

which gets services A, B, C via

```
wasmBuilder.GetRequiredService<T(A)>...
```

and then

```
A.MySetupValues = await B.GetSetupValues().
```

The values are retrieved through the WebApi.

That works so far. But when I use A in a component via [Inject] A a, the service object I get is not the one I retrieved in LoadSetupData (service has a Guid property, they are different).

_2.

I tried adding A by providing a factory method to AddScoped. That doesn't work because getting Values from a WebApi is intrinsically asynchronous. And asynchronous calls can't be used from program.cs/main ("Cannot wait on monitors on this runtime").

Thank you very much for reading! Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: `async LoadSetupData(wasmBuilder)` is neither a call nor a definition, just invalid C#. Do you await it?

Comment: It's pseudocode! Yes, I did await it.

Comment: Too pseudo. You will get pseudo answers that way. Read about [mre]

Comment: Why do you need to pre-load the data?  Get it when the first component wants it.  You say "I've got a service A that is shared among various components."   Then you start talking about Services A,B,C.  if Service A is scoped yet you get different guids then you are most likely restarting the SPA.  Components A, B,C.... will all get the same instance of Scoped Service A in the same SPA "session".   Same thoughts as above on "pseudo code".

Comment: If you think you have to discuss how to use pseudocode then you don't understand pseudocode. It goes directly against its purpose to pettily discuss its details. I vote to stop this disuccion now, since it is not beneficial to anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all of your answers! I was able to resolve the problem by doing the Initialization in the App Component in OnInitializedAsync.

```
[Inject] IServiceProvider sp { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() {

  ISvcB svcb = sp.GetRequiredService<ISvcB>();
  ISvcA svca = sp.GetRequiredService<ISvcA>();

  svca.SetupData = await svcb.GetSetupData();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the Program.cs you can load your data and then indicate how to resolve the dependancy injection.

```
var datas = await (new TheProvidingDataService()).LoadDataAsync();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(s => new NeedYourDataService(data));
```

Comment: although I think my answer is correct, you should have a look at 
https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/domain-model-purity-completeness/
before consider it. There is a price (and a reward) of loading datas at the edge of the application.

Comment: _There is a price (and a reward) of loading datas at the edge of the application_. I don't think there is a price, could have an higher starting time, but from a "global" performance point of view I think it's a booster. If the server has enough memory is a good practice to load all the possible data that don't change frequently in memory. Do you preferer a "lighter" approach? More "DDD"/slim stylish?

Comment: if the amount of data is limited, (reference data) it suits well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to redefine your design.

I prefer to have all the initialization of the service in the constructor.
You need some other services (B & C), so you need to use DI in the constructor of the service A.

### SOLUTION "A"

I think the following design should work for your case:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IServiceA,ServiceA>();

var hostInstance = builder.services.Build();
var theServiceA = hostInstance.GetRequiredService<IServiceA>();

...

hostInstance.RunAsync()
```

### SOLUTION "B"

Try this one in alternatives:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IServiceA>().LoadSetupData());
```

Just a note to anyone, in Blazor WASM *Scoped* and *Singleton* life time are the same. Not in Server.

Comment: I do think your soluton would work. I try to keep my construnctors fast and simple, though. Loading data from a WebApi kind of goes against that idea.